# What causes strange line artifacts to appear in plots with certain PlotRanges?

Tags: plotting

I have seen this strange plotting artifact occur before and I was able to make it go away by changing the PlotRange.  However, this time I need the prescribed PlotRange to be what I define and I get a strange vertical line within my plot.

The questions are, "What causes this?" and "How do I prevent it from happening?"  This is happening for me in Version 9.0 on Mac and Windows.

Here is the code:

```
ur[x_, a_] := 1 - (1/a) Log[1 + a x]
g[x_, go_, s_, m_] := 1/2 (go x Exp[-(x/s)])/(1 + m x)
uh[x_, a_, go_, s_, m_, k_] := ur[x, a] + g[x, go, s, m]/(1 - g[x, go, s, m]) (k - 1)

a = 5; go = 1; s = 2; m = 0.5; 

plt[k_] := ParametricPlot[{ uh[x, a, go, s, m, k], x}, {x, 0, 1}, 
           AspectRatio -> 1/1.5, Frame -> True, PlotStyle -> {Darker[Green]}, 
           FrameLabel -> {Style["Volume Compression", 14], 
           Style["Normalized Pressure", 14]}, 
           LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Times"}]

Show[Table[plt[k], {k, 1.0, 3.5, 0.5}], PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1.2}}]
```

The resulting graphic is produced with the line artifact at x=0.65.  Not certain as to why this happens.  If I tweak the PlotRange to `PlotRange -> {{0.6, 1.4}, {0, 1.2}}` the line goes away.  However, I need the PlotRange to be `PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1.2}}`.  If I move the PlotRange into the ParametricPlot function I get the same result.

[image: Plot with line artifact at x=0.65]

Thanks in advance for any assistance...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is the y-axis. `Frame -> True` does not always turn off the `Axes` when it is supposed to. Looking at the `Options` passed to `Graphics` shows this clearly

```
FilterRules[
  Options@Show[Table[plt[k], {k, 1.0, 3.5, 0.5}], PlotRange -> {{0.5, 1.5}, {0, 1.2}}],
  {Axes, AxesOrigin}]
(* {Axes -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0.65, 0}} *)
```

and `AxesOrigin` explains why you see the artifact at `x = 0.65`.

To fix that add `Axes -> False` to `plt`. Then, it disappears:

[image]

Comment: , AxesOrigin -> {0, 0} is also ok

Comment: Or turn the Frame off `Frame->False`

Comment: That was the issue!  Never would have guessed that one, Thank you!

Comment: @HyperGroups in this case, yes. But, turning off the `Axes` entirely is superior as you do not have to manually set the origin off screen.

Comment: @bills works, except if you want the `Frame`.

Comment: @Joseph You're welcome. It is interesting to note that I have been using it long enough that it was my first guess.

Comment: @rcollyer Ha!  Axes were my first, second, and fourth guesses. :-)

Comment: @BrettChampion I did not bother coming up with additional guesses because I was _almost_ completely certain that that was the trouble. Testing confirmed the guess, obviating the need for further speculation.

Comment: But, why does this happen!? I fortunately found this thread, I also had the same bug.

Comment: @Vicent as it says above, `Frame -> True` is supposed to set `Axes -> False`, but it usually doesn't. So, if it pops-up, you have to explicitly set `Axes -> False`. There are a number of cases where I deliberately set `Frames -> True` and `Axes -> True`, so it isn't all bad, just unexpected.

Comment: I've just encountered this bug on Mathematica 10. This fix worked for me. +1