# Weird vertical line when trying to plot a histogram

Tags: plotting, histograms

I'm trying to plot a histogram of a few data points and overlay a plot on it (it's a fit of a geometric distribution to my data). The weird thing is that a vertical line appears always next to the smallest datapoint of the histogram. As the distribution is continuous, I always get this vertical line in the middle of the plot, and I'd like to get rid of it.

```
p[s_] := 1/(1 + s); q[s_] := s/(1 + s);
Geom[s_, x_] := p[s] (q[s]^x);
SigmaC = 9114.738337867104`;
data = {4.566649578817866`, 4.1087341086023645`, 3.5448119117577757`, 4.191562787591725`, 3.7948364578145606`, 4.157517208532611`,    4.539966367996713`, 3.8003045775561977`, 2.60422605308447`,   4.220081924933814`, 4.166548514738755`, 3.879841055986562`,    3.673481697073347`, 3.310480891462675`, 4.680335513414563`};
Hist = Histogram[data, 10, "PDF"];
Pl = Plot[Log[10] 10^s Geom[SigmaC, 10^s], {s, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Thick}];    
Show[Hist, Epilog -> First@Pl, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1.5}},  Frame -> True]
```

[image]

When I set

```
Frame -> False
```

then the vertical line changes into y-axis. I'd like to have y-axis in the far-left side of the plot. Does anyone have an idea how to resolve this? This is probably really simple but I'd appreciate any insight!

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you seen the `AxesOrigin` option?

Comment: Try `Axes -> False`

Comment: [Similar question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/24882/17).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting the `Axes` option to either `False` or `None` will work.

```
Show[Hist, Epilog -> First@Pl, PlotRange -> {{0, 5}, {0, 1.5}}, Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot Sjoerd, it's exactly what I needed!